# Python Requests Proxy error 'Failed to parse'

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape a page using a list of proxies.
This small problem is litrally driving me nuts. It works when i input the proxy directly like this:

```
proxies = {
            'http': 'http://10.0.1.1:8080',
            'https': 'http://10.0.1.1:8080'
        }
```

But when i use something like

```
http_proxy =  'http://'+proxy
https_proxy = 'https://'+proxy



    proxies = {
            'http': http_proxy,
            'https': https_proxy,
        }
```

> requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.LocationParseError: Failed to
>   parse: 10.0.1.1:8080

I get this error. This makes absolutely no sense.

Edit: i just realized its probably because of the newline after each proxy i have the proxylist.txt hosted on a server so now i need to find out how to get rid of the newline after each proxy i tried stuff like proxy.strip('\n') but that didn't work either

Comment: Must be something else going on, I take it this isn't all the code.

Comment: @Chris Yes i just realized its probably because of the newline after each proxy i have the proxylist.txt hosted on a server so now i need to find out how to get rid of the newline after each proxy i tried stuff like proxy.strip('\n') but that didn't work either

Comment: Post samples and I can help you.

Comment: @Chris Alright so heres what i've tried
r = requests.get('https://proxysite.txt')
y = r.text.rstrip('\\r')
x = y.split('\n')

now i see this in the x variable ['1.12.1.1:122\r', '18.1.1.1:122\r', '9.12.6.8:122\r', '51.

Comment: Okay finally fixed it using proxies = splitlines(). Can't believe wasted so much time on such a simple solution haha

Comment: try printing your variables as you go, especially the ones you're getting errors on to make sure they contain exactly what you think they contain.

Answer (score 3):

I was going crazy because of that problem.

Try to do this:

```
def chomp(x):
    if x.endswith("\r\n"):
        return x[:-2]
    if x.endswith("\n") or x.endswith("\r"):
        return x[:-1]
    return x

http_proxy =  'http://' + chomp(proxy)
https_proxy = 'https://' + chomp(proxy)

proxies = {
       'http': http_proxy,
       'https': https_proxy,
    }
```

It helped solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Always check after using .split could have extra characters i fixed my project using

```
splitlines()
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried proxylist.txt with 2 lines
10.0.1.1:8080
10.0.1.1:8181

and executed below code,

```
with open('proxylist.txt','r') as reader :
    for line in reader :
        proxy = line.split('\n', 1)[0]
        http_proxy =  'http://'+proxy
        https_proxy = 'https://'+proxy

        proxies = {
            'http': http_proxy,
            'https': https_proxy,
        }

        print proxies
```

Got output as expected,
{'http': 'http://10.0.1.1:8080', 'https': 'https://10.0.1.1:8080'}
{'http': 'http://10.0.1.1:8181', 'https': 'https://10.0.1.1:8181'}

Comment: You're probably on a *nix system, as @taijamen said he had problems with CR characters (this means he probably uses Windows or similar).

Answer (score 0):

Another dump option is that the proxy itself is not good anymore. I tried running the same code with one proxy and received this error. None of the solutions above helped me (and actually I believe they fixed this problem in newer versions: https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/4613). However, when I tried using good proxy I didn't encounter this type of problem